# changing variable value inside IF loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

I have a function which accepts value 1-5, and I want to declare a global variable called 'Des' and make it change according to the option selected because I want to use that value in another function. I tried this but it does not work.

```
def mainNJ():
    #S_menu()
    print( "\033[1m" " PLEASE SELECT THE TYPE OF DONATION.")
    global Des
    validate = False
    while not validate:
        option = input(" INPUT VALUE 1 TO 5 : " "\033[0m")

    # For Selection 1 Animal Protection And Welfare.
        if option == str(1):
            validate = True
            print()
            print("\033[1m" " Animal Protection And Welfare Has Been Selected." "\033[0m")
            #Amount()
            Des1 = " Animal Protection And Welfare Has Been Selected."
            Des = Des1

    # For Selection 2 Support For Natural Disaster.
        elif option == str(2):
            validate = True
            print()
            print("\033[1m" " Support For Natural Disaster Has Been Selected." "\033[0m")
            #Amount()
            Des2 = " Support For Natural Disaster Has Been Selected."
            Des = Des2
    # For Selection 3 Children Education And Activities.
        elif option == str(3):
            validate = True
            print()
            print("\033[1m" " Children Education And Activities Has Been Selected." "\033[0m")
            #Amount()
            Des3 = " Children Education And Activities Has Been Selected."
            Des = Des3
    # For Selection 4 Children Education And Activities.
        elif option == str(4):
            validate = True
            print()
            print("\033[1m" " Caregiving And Health Research Has Been Selected." "\033[0m")
            #Amount()
            Des4 = " Caregiving And Health Research Has Been Selected."
            Des = Des4
    # For Selection 5 Conservation Of Cultural Arts.
        elif option == str(5):
            validate = True
            print()
            print("\033[1m" " Conservation Of Cultural Arts Has Been Selected." "\033[0m")
            #Amount()
            Des5 = " Conservation Of Cultural Arts Has Been Selected."
            Des = Des5

        else:
            print()
            print(" Invalid Option. Please Try Again.")
            #S_menu()
```

Comment: are the calls to Amount and S_Menu relevant to the issue? If not, you may want to remove them from your code as they prevent others from running it as is.

Comment: @Roy2012 Noted, I commented them out.

Comment: how about using classes instead of global variables?

Comment: Why do you think your code is not working? Des is assigned a value at the end of your code.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use global variables.

Comment: @juha I am relatively new to python so I have not yet explored classes..

Comment: Maybe, if Des is not defined outside of function, you are trying to access it before it was assigned. i.e. you are doing something with Des before making `mainNJ()` call

Comment: @quamrana I understand, how can I use a certain variable in a function which is declared inside another function?

Comment: @Superior I am accessing it after mainNJ() is called I am sure about that but for some reason it still does not work.

Comment: and what is not working for you, what error does it throw, or what value is it assigned to

Comment: You pass variables as parameters between functions.

Comment: can you output the error message, it will help narrow what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You assign Des to Desx and that is a string. You need to assign it to int(option)

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe, if Des is not defined outside of function, you are trying to access it before it > > was assigned. i.e. you are doing something with Des before making mainNJ() call

to give solution, if this is problem

in another function, where you use it

```py
try:
    print(Des) # example of usage
except NameError: 
    print("Des not yet created")
    # also you can put return statement so function does not continue
    # or call mainNJ() here
```